# Yet another 100% height issue with nested divs, toolbars

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create some toolbars that are on the top, side, and bottom of a div that is set 100% height.  Inside that div will be an iframe which also needs to have a 100% height.

I can get the top toolbar and sidebar toolbar but can't get the main content div/iframe and the footer to work correctly.  The toolbars must surround the main content div/iframe and all 3 of them can be hidden so the main content div/iframe must be able to expand to fill that space.

[plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HULT78hmBmgtrQLQY4U0?p=preview)

The problem is the viewerContainer and footerToolbar divs.  The viewerContainer needs to fill the page regardless of whether or not the toolbars are there or not:

```
    <div id="viewerContainer" style="position:static;top:0;left:0;height: ??%;">
      <div id="viewer_wrapper" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
        <iframe id="viewer_control" name="viewer_control" frameborder="5" style="position: relative;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
        </iframe>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div id="footerToolbar" class=" form-group " style="background:orange;width:100%; "> could be hidden
    </div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to position the toolbars as absolute, so that they do not take up any space. You can then add padding to the sides of the iframe so that it doesnt go over the toolbars.

The padding of the iframe should be as much as the height of the toolbars.

```
#topToolbar {position: absolute; top: 0;}
#footerToolbar {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
#viewer_control {padding: 30px 0 30px 0;}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you need your div element to cover the 100% height then you can use

```
height:100vh;
```

'vh' unit stands for viewport height and makes the element cover full height available.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies but those did not work.  I finally got it to work but had to switch the viewerContainer class depending on which toolbars were visible and have those classes use the calc height.  Since we are using angular in the main project this made it easy to do.